# How to write unique CSS in extension so that it wont affect the sites in which it is rendered?

Tags: html, css

I am basically trying to build a chrome extension where I will be displaying my modules in all the sites.

Basic extension usage -

When I click on my extension there will be many popup modals which will be rendered in websites.

Problem -
These extension popup modals as a specific set of CSS which is being overwritten by the site CSS.

Sass Approach -
To avoid overwrite in css from existing site to extension I used the following approaches,

1. CSS Specificity

Where I had a parent class for my extension modal and inside it I will be writing all my css classes.

```
.parent{
     & .header{
         //css properties
     }
 }
```

2. CSS reset

Where when loading my extension all basic elements will be set to initial

```
   input[type="text"]{
       all:initial;
       border-radius: 3px;
       padding: 8px 10px;
       width: inherit;
       border: 1px solid #c8ccd0;
       -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -ms-border-radius: 3px;
      -o-border-radius: 3px;
       visibility: inherit;
       font-weight: 200;
       line-height: 0;
  }
```

3. Using !important

All these approaches I tried but still there are few cases where my CSS is being overwritten by the existing sites.

Failure Cases -

For example - In my extension modal if I have a button element and I have given background-color as blue

```
button{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

In the site where the extension is loaded as a property of

```
button{
    background-color:red !important
}
```

Then it automatically takes the site property and its being overwritten in my extension css.

Solution Needed
It will be great if someone provides me a idea how to use a css for extension so that its not going to be affected by existing sites CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you write css you either follow

1. [BEM(Block Element Modifier)](http://getbem.com/introduction/) technique.
2. You can give a specific `pefix` to the css `class` or `id`.
3. You can try injecting custom html tags which you can then use to point the styles out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with writing the CSS more specifically to prevent the !important tags overwriting your CSS.

For example:

```
div.CLASS-NAME > button.CLASS-NAME {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

Might be worth reading up on CSS specificity - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html